# Make always one panel open with GXT AccordionLayoutContainer

Tags: menu, gxt

I would like to create something like GWT Stack Panel, but with GXT. I've found AccordionLayoutContainer. The problem is that using AccordionLayoutContainer there is possibility to collapse all panels in menu (see the picture).

[image]

I would like to have always one panel open like in GWT Stack Panel.

Here is the code of my menu:

```
public class MenuPanel extends ContentPanel implements LazyView, IsWidget {

ContentPanel detailsContentPanel;
ContentPanel actionsContentPanel;
ContentPanel logsContentPanel;
ContentPanel filesContentPanel;
ContentPanel assessmentContentPanel;
ContentPanel contactsContentPanel;

AccordionLayoutContainer menuContainer;

@Override
public void createView() {

    setHeadingText("Menu");
    setHeight("100%");
    setWidth("100%");

    menuContainer = new AccordionLayoutContainer();
    menuContainer.setExpandMode(AccordionLayoutContainer.ExpandMode.SINGLE_FILL);
    menuContainer.setHeight("100%");

    add(menuContainer);


    AccordionLayoutContainer.AccordionLayoutAppearance appearance = GWT.<AccordionLayoutContainer.AccordionLayoutAppearance>
            create(AccordionLayoutContainer.AccordionLayoutAppearance.class);


    detailsContentPanel = new ContentPanel(appearance);
    detailsContentPanel.setAnimCollapse(false);
    detailsContentPanel.setHeadingText("Details");
    menuContainer.add(detailsContentPanel);

    logsContentPanel = new ContentPanel(appearance);
    logsContentPanel.setAnimCollapse(false);
    logsContentPanel.setHeadingText("Logs");
    menuContainer.add(logsContentPanel);

    actionsContentPanel = new ContentPanel(appearance);
    actionsContentPanel.setAnimCollapse(false);
    actionsContentPanel.setHeadingText("Actions");
    menuContainer.add(actionsContentPanel);

    filesContentPanel = new ContentPanel(appearance);
    filesContentPanel.setAnimCollapse(false);
    filesContentPanel.setHeadingText("Files");
    menuContainer.add(filesContentPanel);

    assessmentContentPanel = new ContentPanel(appearance);
    assessmentContentPanel.setAnimCollapse(false);
    assessmentContentPanel.setHeadingText("Assessments");
    menuContainer.add(assessmentContentPanel);

    contactsContentPanel = new ContentPanel(appearance);
    contactsContentPanel.setAnimCollapse(false);
    contactsContentPanel.setHeadingText("Contacts");
    menuContainer.add(contactsContentPanel);
}
```

}

Can You please help me with this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: menuContainer.setActiveWidget(detailsContentPanel);//Try this

Comment: This will only open detailsContentPanel, but then if you click on "Details" from menu, then again you will have collapsed all elements from menu. The issue is to make impossible to collapse open element after click on it. One and only one element should always be opened.

Comment: setCollapsable(false) on the contentpanel

Comment: Nothing changed in the behaviour of the menu.

Comment: override collapse() method on contentpanel which u want to disable collapsable.

Comment: I think that you don't understand my problem. If I make collapse impossible then the panel will never be closed. The issue is to have always one panel open, so if on the begining you have opened Details panel and then you would like to open Logs, the details panel should automaticly be closed. And it is working properly with AccordionLayoutContainer but when I will click on the opened panel it shouldn't be closed. Please take a look on [GWT Stack Panel](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwStackLayoutPanel). This is exactly what I need but using GXT.